# Did the 64GB iPhone SE ever ship with iOS 10 installed?

Tags: iphone

I want to get an iPhone SE with iOS 9.  I think any new, never-used 64GB iPhone SE will have iOS 9 on it since I don't believe they ever shipped out with iOS 10 pre-installed, but I'm not certain.  Does anyone know if the 64GB models ever came with iOS 10 and if so, when that began?

Answer (score 3):

According to [EveryMac.com/EveryiPhone.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-se-a1662-united-states-att-tmobile-verizon-specs.html), the 64GB SE was sold (in the US because you didn't specify a different country) with iOS 9.3 preinstalled.

iOS 10 came out in September, 2016 and I believe all iPhones after that date came with 10 preinstalled, including the 64GB model.  I can shop the Best Buy near me and they've [advertised](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-iphone-se-64gb-space-gray-verizon/5005516.p?skuId=5005516) a 64GB SE with iOS 10 preinstalled.  You'd need to ensure the one you're looking to purchase was distributed prior to September.

As a standard disclaimer, I would not recommend you stay with iOS 9.  Many security enhancements were issued, and continue to be issued, with the latest versions.  You leave yourself wide-open to being compromised with an older OS.

Comment: And that's what confuses me.  I'm replacing another phone that I bought on November 28 2016 that came with iOS 9 (my wife accidentally upgraded to iOS 10 recently and hates it).  So clearly at least Verizon was still shipping phones through November with iOS 9.  Sounds like there may not be any way to be 100% certain what version the phone has on it, if it's not been used yet.

Comment: Those were probably manufactured prior to iOS 10.  I think the only way would be to check the box and see what's listed.

Comment: Yeah the box doesn't say unfortunately. just model number, part number, serial number, etc.  Nothing at all about the software installed.

Comment: Also to address your edit - It's a bit hyperbolic IMO.  This is not an issue of security, it has to do with the fact that in my wife's view Apple has now ruined her phone by installing an OS she never wanted.  They make it quite difficult for her as a non-techie to avoid installing with their aggressive popups.  One slip of the finger and your phone has been permanently altered in ways you may not be happy about.  It amazes me that more users aren't up in arms over such tactics - we should be free to run whatever supported OS version we prefer on our iOS devices, just like with any Mac.

Comment: No problem, I was just calling it out primarily for others that might come across your question.   FWIW, my wife was the same about her SE and it took a few days of using iOS 10 to learn to really like it.  To each his/her own!  Also, that wasn't part of my edit, it was in the original answer :-).

Comment: Ah I guess I was just fixated on the answer to my question and didn't see the final bit.  Anyway I still don't believe one is "wide open to being compromised" by running an older OS.  We still run iOS 6, and 7, on various devices. They continue to work great and unless it's been incredibly subtle, we've never been compromised once.  The statement makes it sound like if you ever go out into the world with an older-OS phone, some nefarious hacker is going to remotely pwn it in seconds.  Heck I can't put iOS10 on my 4s even if I wanted to.

Comment: These comments will be shut-down soon and pushed to chat so pls google ios9 security flaws.  Here's list of fixes in 10: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207143